# Convergence in mean in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots$ be random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose they are i.i.d with mean zero. Given an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$,
 I want to know how fast $\mathbb{E}[\|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\|^{2}]$ tends to zero.

For example, if $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, then it is an elementary result from statistics that
$ \mathbb{E}[\|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\|_2^{2}]\leq \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[\|a_1\|_2^{2}]$.

If we have another norm, then because norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent,  I can say that there is a $C$ *depending on the particular norm* such that
$\mathbb{E}[\|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i\|^{2}] \leq \frac{C}{n}\mathbb{E}[\|a_1\|^{2}]$.

However, in my application I need to find such a $C$ that works simultaneously for many (infinitely many) norms. Is this possible?

Comment: Which norms do you need it to work for?

Comment: @Jack M Ideally it is one C to be used for all norms on the space.